# Handle empty dataWrap in typoscript

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I've 'inherited' the following typoscript snippet, which should produce rendered `tt_content` records when referenced in a `tx_extension_domain_model_item` record:

```
lib.recordBasedHighlight = CONTENT
lib.recordBasedHighlight {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid 

    select.andWhere.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
    select.andWhere.stdWrap.cObject {
        dataWrap = DB:tx_extension_domain_model_item:{GP:tx_extension_pi1|item}:referenced_content
        wrap3 = uid IN ({|})
        insertData = 1
    }
    select.pidInList.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
    select.pidInList.stdWrap.cObject {
        dataWrap = DB:tx_extension_domain_model_item:{GP:tx_extension_pi1|item}:pid
        wrap3 = {|}
        insertData = 1
    }

    renderObj < tt_content
    renderObj.list.10 >
}
```

This works fine when the `referenced_content` field has some actual content referenced (the value would then be a `tt_content` uid). When this is not the case the `wrap3` statement results in `uid IN ()`, which, as should be expected, throws a SQL error.

I've tried to add `required = 1` to the `.select.andWhere.stdWrap.cObject` configuration, which results in all content being fetched from the pid in `pidInList` when no content is referenced, as the `andWhere` clause is emptied when that field is empty.

How should the above script snippet be altered so the correct `tt_content` records are rendered and no records are rendered when the `referenced_content` is empty?

Comment: Please use `intval = 1` to prevent SQL injections!

Comment: Good point, although I'm not sure where to put that, as the only variable it's applicable to is `GP:tx_extension_pi1|item`. And although there's no expicit casting to an integer, the way this piece of typoscript is implemented the only way it is executed is when a valid UID is passed in the GET parameter (by way of a controller action property). I did try to pass other information to the script by requesting a number of URLs with the GET parameter with some random content, having added xdebug break points in the code to inspect what was going on, but nothing was passed to the database.

Comment: Having said that, could you indicate where the intval should be placed to make sure the GET/POST parameter is cast to an integer? I wouldn't hurt to add it, after all. :)

Comment: I would do this with an orderedStdWrap, so you can do it step by step. See: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/UsingStdWrap/ModifyTheOrder/Index.html

Comment: Better documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#orderedstdwrap

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try to transform the code using orderedStdWrap, although it's not readily obvious to me how it would be implemented. That's going to take me some time. Thanks for the pointer, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed obvious to do something with `ifEmpty`, but I just couldn't get it right. Until I tried to change things a bit radically. The following works for me:

```
lib.recordBasedHighlight = CONTENT
lib.recordBasedHighlight {
    table = tt_content
    select.orderBy = sorting
    select.languageField = sys_language_uid 

    select.andWhere.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
    select.andWhere.stdWrap.cObject {
        stdWrap {
            cObject = TEXT
            cObject {
                # NOT SAFE: GET/POST parameter is passed on to the database without sanitation
                dataWrap = DB:tx_extension_domain_model_item:{GP:tx_extension_pi1|item}:referenced_content
                wrap3 = {|}
                insertData = 1
            }
            ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
            ifEmpty.cObject.value = 0
        }
        wrap = uid IN (|)
    }
    select.pidInList.stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
    select.pidInList.stdWrap.cObject {
        # NOT SAFE: GET/POST parameter is passed on to the database without sanitation
        dataWrap = DB:tx_extension_domain_model_item:{GP:tx_extension_pi1|item}:pid
        wrap3 = {|}
        insertData = 1
    }

    renderObj < tt_content
    renderObj.list.10 >
}
```

This results in `andWhere` being `uid IN (0)` when the `referenced_content` field is empty. That results in no `tt_content` records being rendered, which is what I was after.

I'm aware of the fact that this snippet will result in a SQL query of which beforehand is known to not return any results, but the alternative is to write better typoscript (not my forte) or rewrite it all into a userFunc. In any case it would be more work and with TYPO3 being quite resource intensive a single query more won't hurt. So I'm satisfied with the solution.

**EDIT**

As [Thomas Löffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4432648/thomas-l%C3%B6ffler) rightfully pointed out in the first comment on the original question, there is a big security omission in the code snippet: the used GET parameter is not sanitised before being passed on to the database. I've not taken the time to rewrite the snippet to include the proposed security measure, although in the project in which the code snippet is used this is not so relevant (see my comment for a more elaborate explanation). That doesn't mean that the code snippet is safe in all circumstances, which leads me to include a warning in this answer: **the code snippet is not inherently secure! Please use this snippet at your own discretion!**